# Ping from subinterface

Tags: debian, centos, networking, network-interface, ping

I have a sub-interface `eth0:0`

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.96
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.2.1
```

and I try

```
ping -I eth0:0 8.8.8.8
```

and I get

```
ping: SO_BINDTODEVICE: Invalid argument
```

If I ping from normal interface (`eth0`) everything is OK.

I tried it on Ubuntu 14.04 and CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define eth0:0 as the origin of your ICMP packet with the `ping`command; as said in previous comments, the routing rules will be applied, and if routing to other networks, the eth0 address will be used.

You can however, spoof an ICMP packet having eth0:0 IP address as origin with the `hping3` command as in:

```
sudo hping3 -1 8.8.8.8 -a 192.168.2.96
```

Please do note that for it to work, your border router has to do NAT for the 192.168.2.0/24 netblock.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you ping an address in your network

```
192.168.2.0/24
```

the eth0:0 address will be used as source. Otherwise, the Interface address of eth0 will be used.

Comment: So you are saying that I cannot ping external IP from `eth0:0` ?